# convert usercontrol control to style

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, styles

hi im new in wpf I have a control that has been created in user control I want to create this control in style I do not know what to do:
this is xaml codes:
https://gist.github.com/ghost1372/8b3db759241b3ddb838789e446efb0b4#file-multiselectcombo-xaml

and this is cs codes:
https://gist.github.com/ghost1372/8b3db759241b3ddb838789e446efb0b4#file-multiselectcombo-cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well basically all you have to do is to define a Style and set the properties using Setters. Something like:

```
<Style x:Key="MultiSelectCombo" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!-- Put the control template you used in your UserControl -->

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!-- Put the DataTemplate you used in your UserControl -->

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now this style can be applied to any ComboBox and will change its look. However if you want also change the behavior you need to create a MultiSelectCombo class that overrides ComboBox and implements the logic you want.